Connection Abbreviations on my plate amplifier control board and amplifier board
I've been looking everywhere for a common list of abbreviations found on my plate amplifier boards.  They're located on the board connections that tell me what wires do what between the tone control/pre-amp control to the amplifier or switching power supply.  Take a look at the pictures to see what I mean. I'm not even sure if there is a universal glossary of terms, but I'll take whatever help I can get.


It would hep to also include a picture of the connector and the other side to which the wires go.

The +15v, -15v, and GND labels are pretty obvious for DC power and ground, so you're looking for the meanings of STA, PRT, and SIN, right?

What is a plate amplifier board?
